# How can I send GET request with sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, get, request, send

I want to send GET/POST request with sockets, and I have this code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(Url, 80);
byte[] contentLenght = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
string[] masRequestString ={
    "GET /"+Data+" HTTP/1.1\r\n" ,
    "Host: "+Url+"\r\n",
    "User-Agent: "+textBox1.Text+"\r\n",
    "Accept:     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n",
    "Referer: "+textBox2.Text+"\r\n"};
string request = string.Concat(masRequestString);
Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
socket.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);
Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[0x400];
int bytes = socket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
```

When I try to send the request sniffers don't see it. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea of how you do sniffing but

- You are at not sending a correct request, because it misses an `\r\n` at the end.
- You are expecting the server to close the connection after the response is done. Instead you need to care about `content-length` header and chunked encoding.
- And apart from that sending a `Content-type` header with a GET request makes no sense, because there will be no content sent inside a GET request (only in the response).

I suggest you first get a deeper knowledge of HTTP works before you are trying to implement it. Much better of course would be to use already existing implementations, because HTTP is not the simply protocol it seems to be after having only a short look.

Answer (score -2):

Don't try implement HTTP yourself, socket can take your data and wrap it.
Use HTTP library:

```
using System.Net;

string url = "https://www.example.com/scriptname.php?var1=hello";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```